# Two way binding for UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rx-swift

I'm new to RXSwift. I have UITableViewCell, which has a button. I need to change button state once I click on select all button which is outside of the tableview. I'm changing view model value but UI is not getting updated. Following way I'm binding, how to bind it two ways?

```
var isSelectedAttendee: Variable<Bool>
cellViewModel?.isSelectedAttendee.asObservable().bind(to: selectButton.rx.isSelected).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Its not duplicated, simple button binding I know but in my case button is inside UITableViewCell. I have tried with different solutions but it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two way binding in RxSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496074/two-way-binding-in-rxswift)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this it is, the author has already answered this

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/606